# macOS - Difference between /Library/Preferences/ & /Library/Managed\ Preferences

Tags: mojave, preferences, plist

Just for my learning and knowledge purpose why some .plist files are saved inside of `/Library/Preferences/` and some others are saved inside of `/Library/Managed\ Preferences`?

Basically what is the purpose of differentiate the location of .plist among these two specific directories?

Side Note: the macOS system is managed by an MDM solution.

Thanks

Comment: You wouldn't by chance have some sort of MDM software installed, would you?

Comment: No problem, but that should point you in the direction.  That folder doesn't exist on machines that aren't managed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed Preferences were used by Casper Suite (now Jamf Pro).

According to the [Casper Suite Administrator's Guide v9.97](https://web.archive.org/web/20161227025450/http://docs.jamf.com/9.97/casper-suite/administrator-guide/Managed_Preferences.html):

> Managed Preferences are manifest files that define preferences for computers and users. You can use the JAMF Software Server (JSS) to create Managed Preference profiles, which contain groups of Managed Preferences. You can also specify the users and computers for which a profile should be applied (called “scope”).

But Managed Preferences has been removed since [Jamf Pro 10.0.0](https://docs.jamf.com/10.0.0/jamf-pro/release-notes/Deprecations_and_Removals.html):

> The following functionality has been removed:
>
> [...]
>
> - Managed Preferences—Support for managed preferences has been removed. It is recommended that you use macOS configuration profiles to define settings and restrictions for computers and users.
>
> [...]

They were based on the now deprecated Managed Client for OS X (MCX).